# How do I append text to item transfered between lists using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to transfer selected items from a list to another list. The source list HTML is

```
    <ul id="source-list">
      <li id="1">Accordion</li>
      <li id="2">Autocomplete</li>
      <li id="3">Tabs</li>  
   </ul>
```

Here is the jquery

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#source-list, #target-list").selectable();

      $("#add-button").click(add);
      $("#remove-button").click(remove);


     addHiglightPlugin();      
     }); 


   }

 function add() {
   transfer($("#source-list li.ui-selected"));
 }   

      function transfer(listItems) {
  alert($(this).data("index", $("#source-list li").index($(this))));
  listItems.fadeOut(function() {
    $(this)
      .removeClass("ui-selected")
      .clone()
      .appendTo("#target-list")
      .fadeIn()
      .data("index", $("#source-list li").index($(this)))
      .highlight();
  });

}
```

When the selected item is transferred, I want to append text to it. For example, if "Accordion" is selected and transferred, I want to destination text to read "Accordion - Click here to view photo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it after you clone it and before you fade it in -

```
 $(this)
      .removeClass("ui-selected")
      .clone()
      .appendTo("#target-list")
      .html( $(this).html() + ' - Click here to view photo' )
      .fadeIn()
      .data("index", $("#source-list li").index($(this)))
      .highlight();
```

I added a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/CvUUL/) to demonstrate the technique.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle